# pyglet custom mouse graphics

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm learning pyglet since yesterday and I'm doing a step by step tutorial. Unfortunately, I can't get my program to change the mouse icon. Here's the code:

```
import pyglet


def create_window(width, height):
    return pyglet.window.Window(width=width,
                                height=height,
                                caption="Pyglet library")


def load_cursor(filename):
    image = pyglet.image.load(filename)
    return pyglet.window.ImageMouseCursor(image, 16, 16)


window = create_window(640, 480)
cursor = load_cursor("Example.png")
window.set_mouse_cursor(cursor)


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()


pyglet.app.run()
```

My mouse icon won't show, and even the standard icon won't show. There is no mouse cursor on screen. Thanks for help in advance.